# If two identical transformers are connected in parallel, referring to LV(secondary) side, any change?

Tags: transformer

Assume transformers are `10/0.4 kV` `500kVA` transformers. Primary is high voltage side and secondary is the low voltage side.

Normally we do `Z_secondary(LV) = Z_primary(HV) * (Vrated2(LV)/Vrated1(HV))^2` to refer impedances from primary to secondary in case of a single transformer. My question is, if instead, two identical transformers were connected in parallel, will the referring be the same? Or will there be any changes in the above formula?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, with ideal transformers with infinite magnetization (primary) inductance, the formula for impedance transformation is: -

$$Z_{primary} = \left[\dfrac{N_p}{N_s}\right]^2\cdot Z_{secondary}$$

But because there is magnetization inductance (\$X_L\$) the above formula becomes: -

$$Z_{primary} = X_L||\left[\dfrac{N_p}{N_s}\right]^2\cdot Z_{secondary}$$

And with two identical parallel transformers, the formula becomes: -

$$Z_{primary} = \dfrac{X_L}{2}||\left[\dfrac{N_p}{N_s}\right]^2\cdot Z_{secondary}$$

Just switch this formula around to solve for the secondary impedance.

And, just in case there is any doubt about what \$X_L\$ is, I include the equivalent circuit for a transformer (to avoid ambiguity): -

[image]

If you need to consider leakage inductance then \$L_P\$ and \$L_S\$ are shown above in their circuit positions.

Comment: indeed, I am interested on the modelling of transformers in power distrubiton systems. We(in classes) make some simplifications in our modellings. We do replace a transformer only with a reactance which we calculate with `uk(%) * Vrated(l-to-l)^2/Srated(3-ph)` and call is `Xs` generally. I assume we omit the `X_L` you mentioned. I think our `X_s` is leakage inductance only.  So, if you also think that we do not include your XL in our transformer modelling based on my writings, then parallel connection of transformers will not have any affect the referring formula, right?

Comment: I have added the equivalent circuit of a transformer showing where the leakage inductances are - you should be able to see that they add (in complex math) to the load for LS.

Comment: ok, guess we are not including Lm in our model, in such case, the formula for referring an external impedance connected to the primary to secondary will not be dependent on whether there are more than one identical transformers in parallel or only one of them.

Comment: I cannot guess about Ls, Lm or Lp. I can only point them out to you and suggest what their effect will be should you decide to include them in your model or not.

Comment: yes, but I say that I am willing to omit Lm in my model, forget about it, or consider it is infinitiy(such as open cct). Then, there is no difference between parallel connecting transformers or a single transformer standalone in terms of referring. yes or no?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Comment: actually I just figured that it was never included to the **referring** part of the formula, you were just adding it to the primary side total impedance. Also, shouldn't those XLs be j*XL since they are not impedances but reactances?

Comment: All my symbolic representations of impedance quantities can be assumed to be complex by default (including the secondary impedance). It's probably misleading to say jXL because it would be \$j\omega L\$. I tend to believe that the term \$X_L\$ implicitly contains "j".

Comment: See this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45009/basic-ac-circuit-analysis

Comment: errrr, I think I would've gone with jXL because it comes more appropriate to me. You are right that it is easily understand that it should have a j with it. But, "It's probably misleading to say jXL because it would be jωL." what is wrong with being jwL ? To me, it is an *impedance* and more suitable than a reactance(XL only) to be paralleled with another *impedance*.

Comment: as far as the only concern is the magnitudes of quantites, no problem, but still I think jXL is the more *correct* one. Nevertheless, thanks for your helps.

Comment: Nothing wrong with \$j\omega L\$ - it's \$jX_L\$ that I believe to be wrong because \$X_L\$ has an internal j implied.

Comment: "because XL has an internal j implied. " is this a convention you use yourself, you used to think in such way  or something common?

Comment: It's simply that XL = jwL i.e. there is a "j" within XL.

Comment: ok then, if you check https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Electrical_reactance wikipedia page, inductive reactance and impedance subsections states parallel things with my thoughts.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that early on they defined \$X_L\$ as being \$\omega L\$. If you define it as that then you have to follow up with \$jX_L\$. But, I always choose to define \$X_L\$ as being \$j\omega L\$. I believe my definition is correct but you can arbitrarily say \$jX\$ because you haven't defined what X is.

Comment: "But because there is magnetization inductance (XL) the above formula becomes: -" You defined XL not even a reactance, as an *inductance*.

Comment: I never said inductance **is** XL in that statement. I was referring to inductance having a reactance so that it was clearer what the formula in the next line was. It was shorthand. I mean I could have said *magnetization inductance (having a reactance of XL)* but i didn't feel it was necessary because I assumed it would be clear.

Comment: yes it was clear already, I am totally ok that your answer had created no confusions regarding reactance impedance etc. I am just after to most open(clear, understandable) form of it can be. Anyway, this gone far much than needed, thanks again and have a nice day.